# How to gain access to the accelerometer in Android

Tags: java, android

So I am a beginner in Java/Android, and I am trying to get a simple app which shows the input of the phones accelerator. I got some sample code from a book:

```
package com.example.userinterfaceandvibra;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;



public class MainActivity
    extends Activity
    implements SensorEventListener 
{
    TextView statusTv;
    TextView messagesTv;
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor sensor;
    float g=9.81f;
    float x, y, z;

    /*** Main -- automatically called methods ***/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initGUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initAccel();
        msg("Running.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        closeAccel();
        msg("Paused. \n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        x=event.values[1]/g;
        y=event.values[2]/g;
        z=event.values[3]/g;
        statusTv.setText(String.format("x: %3.2f y: %3.2f, z: %3.2f", x,y,z));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        //Must have when Activity implements SensorEventListener.
    }

    /***  Accelerometer ***/

    void initAccel()
    {
        msg("Accelerometer initialization...");
        sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor=sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
                Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(
                this,
                sensor,
                sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    void closeAccel()
    {
        msg("Accelerometer closing...");
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensor);
    }

    void initGUI()
    {
        //Window
        setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        //Contents
        LinearLayout container=new LinearLayout(this);
        container.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        statusTv = new TextView(this);
        container.addView(statusTv);
        messagesTv = new TextView(this);
        container.addView(messagesTv);
        //Show
        setContentView(container);
        msg("User interface created.");
    }

    public void msg(String s)
    {
        if (7<=messagesTv.getLineCount()) messagesTv.setText("");
        messagesTv.append(s);
    }


}
```

My Code does not run any errors, however when I try to launch it, I get the classic "Unfortunately, myApp has stopped." At first I thought it was due to the fact my app didn't have permission to use the Accelerator, so here is my manifest file where I (hopefully) added the correct code to obtain permission.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.userinterfaceandvibra"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" 
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.userinterfaceandvibra.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Lastly, I looked into log cat to try and see what errors are being thrown. Because I am so new I don't really get most of it, yet it is clear that the first error thrown is "Exception dispatching input event." However I couldn't see a line number, and with the error being so vague I didn't really know what to try next. Just for kicks for all those smarter than me, here is the logcat readout:

```
04-05 20:13:00.084: D/SensorManager(21947): registerListener :: create queue :: handler = 0, name = K330 3-axis Accelerometer, delay = 200000, 
04-05 20:13:00.104: D/SensorManager(21947): unregisterListener ::  
04-05 20:13:00.184: D/SensorManager(21947): registerListener :: create queue :: handler = 0, name = K330 3-axis Accelerometer, delay = 200000, 
04-05 20:13:00.304: D/libEGL(21947): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
04-05 20:13:00.304: D/libEGL(21947): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
04-05 20:13:00.314: D/libEGL(21947): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
04-05 20:13:00.324: I/Adreno-EGL(21947): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
04-05 20:13:00.324: I/Adreno-EGL(21947): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
04-05 20:13:00.324: I/Adreno-EGL(21947): Build Date: 09/26/13 Thu
04-05 20:13:00.324: I/Adreno-EGL(21947): Local Branch: 
04-05 20:13:00.324: I/Adreno-EGL(21947): Remote Branch: 
04-05 20:13:00.324: I/Adreno-EGL(21947): Local Patches: 
04-05 20:13:00.324: I/Adreno-EGL(21947): Reconstruct Branch: 
04-05 20:13:00.424: D/OpenGLRenderer(21947): Enabling debug mode 0
04-05 20:13:00.434: E/SensorManager(21947): Exception dispatching input event.
04-05 20:13:00.434: D/AndroidRuntime(21947): Shutting down VM
04-05 20:13:00.434: W/dalvikvm(21947): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4176d898)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at com.example.userinterfaceandvibra.MainActivity.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:54)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:467)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to learn to read stack traces. It says `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3 index=3`, and identifies line 54 of *MainActivity.java* as the source. Look there and find out why. The logcat output isn't "just for kicks" -- it's the single most important piece of information about what happened.

Comment: This was a stupid post! I can normally make sense of them. I guess I was so caught on the first error I completely skipped the others.I code in c# so I defiantly should have caught the array thing when I copied the code. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it was a stupid post; I'm guessing you probably won't overlook logcat output again, and learning something is generally a win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at logcat error:

```
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
04-05 20:13:00.444: E/AndroidRuntime(21947):    at com.example.userinterfaceandvibra.MainActivity.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:54)
```

The array length is 3 and index being accessed is 3. Since arrays start with index 0, the 3 array elements can be accessed via index 0,1,2. Hence change your onSensorChanged method from:

```
x=event.values[1]/g;
y=event.values[2]/g;
z=event.values[3]/g;
```

to

```
x=event.values[0]/g;
y=event.values[1]/g;
z=event.values[2]/g;
```

Comment: +1 good catch. This answer can be slightly improved if you describe how you knew to look there, so the OP can find these types of issues more easily in the future. :)